# How to execute script using BrowserWindow object in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a [BrowserWindow](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.35.0/api/browser-window/) object that pointing to a website.

```
mainWindow.loadUrl('http://example.com/');
```

Now I want to execute scripts on this website, so I'm looking for a [method](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.35.0/api/browser-window/#methods) like [window.eval](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script) in node-webkit, but I have not found. Anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[webContents.executeJavaScript](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.35.0/api/web-contents/#webcontents-executejavascript-code-usergesture) is the method:

```
myCoolWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('window.close()');
```

Comment: that link says it's not found.. I think [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) is the related link